# ASP.net and MS Office Project integration and exporting it as image

Tags: asp.net, image-processing, ms-office, ms-project

I have requirement of creating MS Project object in asp.net c# and exporting image of it for end user to download.

I can achieve first part of the requirement of creating MS Project object as suggested in following link.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/MS_project_and_Aspnet.aspx?display=Print

but exporting it as image with specific dimensions does not seem to click.

Kindly Advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ASP.NET components like [ActiveGantt](http://sourcecodestore.com/) that will do this for you. Google found many.